# How to use Coldfusoion MOD?

Tags: coldfusion

I have code that grabs events from the FullCalendar.js which works fine.

However, I am having a hard time to style it in a way that in each column, it has two events, breaks and goes to the next column.

The code is written in coldfusion and I read I can use MOD. However, I have tried a if statement and a counter to track how many events are and yet it does not go to the next column

The following is the code I am using. I am trying to target the "More Event" section so that when it hits two events, it breaks and goes to the next column:

```
<!--- Derived from: --->
<!--- https://gist.github.com/stevewithington/18a6ef38e7234f1e1fc3 --->
<!--- Upcoming events --->
<cffunction name="dspDisplayEvents">
    <cfargument name="feedName" type="string" default="8C702325-155D-0201-11D851267D5B4B2B" />
    <cfargument name="maxMonths" type="numeric" default="3" />
    <cfargument name="groupDailyEvents" default="true" />
    <cfscript>
        var rs = '';
        var subRS = '';
        var local = {};
        local.feed = variables.$.getBean('feed').loadBy(name=arguments.feedName).setMaxItems(0).setNextN(0);
        local.listIDs = '';

        /*if ( feed.getIsNew() ) {
            return '<div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Ooops!</strong> The Content Collection/Feed &quot;<strong>#HTMLEditFormat(arguments.feedName)#</strong>&quot; does not exist.</div>';
        }*/

        local.it = feed.getIterator(
            from=Now()
            , to=DateAdd('m', Val(3), Now())
            , maxItems=3
        );
    rs = local.it.getQuery();

    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>
            <!--- #feed.getIsNew()# --->
            <!--- #local.it.hasNext()# --->
            <cfset ctr= 1 />
            <cfloop condition="(local.it.hasNext()) AND (ctr LT 6)">
                <cfset local.item = local.it.next() />
                <cfif not ListFind(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid'))>
                    <cfif ctr eq 1>
                    <!--- TODO: set a default image if no image is available --->
                    <div class="bg-white1 centerEvent"> 
                        <div class="hidden-xs col-md-2 override-col-md-offset-3 margin-left">
                            <p class="image-center upcoming-events-image image-padding"><img src="#local.item.getImageURL()#" alt="#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getTitle())#"> </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2" id="featured-event">
                            <div class="eventCenter">   
                                <h4 class="featured1"><strong>FEATURED EVENT</strong></h4>
                                <hr class="hr" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="eventTop">  
                                <small>
                                    <!--- date --->
                                    <!--- start date --->
                                    #LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#
                                        <!--- end date (if 'daily' event, and grouping is requested) --->
                                        <cfif YesNoFormat(arguments.groupDailyEvents)>
                                            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="subRS">
                                                select *
                                                from rs
                                                where rs.contentid = <cfqueryparam value="#local.item.getValue('contentid')#" />
                                            </cfquery>
                                            <cfif subRS.recordcount gt 1>
                                                <!--- end date --->
                                                <cfset enddate = ListLast(ValueList(subRS.displaystop)) />
                                                <cfif IsValid('date', enddate)>
                                                    - #LSDateFormat(enddate)#
                                                </cfif>
                                            </cfif>
                                            <cfset local.listIDs = ListAppend(local.listIDs, local.item.getValue('contentid')) />
                                        </cfif>
                                </small>
                                <h6 class="ellipsis h6size"><!--- Title --->
                                    <a href="#local.item.getURL()#">
                                        <div class="featured-event-title">
                                            #HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </h6>
                                <div>
                                    <small>
                                        <!--- Summary --->
                                        <div class="featured-event-summary">
                                            <cfif Len(local.item.getValue('summary'))>
                                                #local.item.getValue('summary')#
                                            </cfif>
                                        </div>
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                <a href="##"><small>Learn more &gt;</small></a>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </div><!---eventTop Div--->
                        <cfelse>
                            <cfif ctr eq 2>
                        **<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 <!---eventBox--->" id="more-events">
                                <small><strong class="featured moreCenter">MORE EVENTS</strong></small><br />
                            </cfif>
                            <div class="eventSize eventDiv" style="border: 1px solid black;">

                                    <small>#LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#</small><br />
                                    <small><strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong></small><br />
                            </div>
                                <br />
                    </cfif>
                </cfif>
                <cfset ctr++ />
            </cfloop>**
            <!--- <button class="btn btn-info btn-md resizable" type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://oc2-web03/mura-6.2.6407/index.cfm/news-events/events-calendar/'" ><small>SEE ALL EVENTS &gt;</small></button> --->
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-md resizable buttonHome" type="button" onClick="parent.location='http://oc2-web03/regal_prod/index.cfm/news-events/events-calendar/'" ><small>SEE ALL EVENTS &gt;</small></button><br />
        </div><!---div bg-white1--->
        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction>
```

**UPDATE** This the relevant code I need help to adjust:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 <!---eventBox--->" id="more-events">
                                    <small><strong class="featured moreCenter">MORE EVENTS</strong></small><br />
                                </cfif>
                                <div class="eventSize eventDiv" style="border: 1px solid black;">

                                        <small>#LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#</small><br />
                                        <small><strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong></small><br />
                                </div>
                                    <br />
                        </cfif>
                    </cfif>
                    <cfset ctr++ />
                </cfloop>
```

Any help on how to use MOD or an example would be great.

Comment: What portion of all that code is relevant to the question being asked?

Comment: @DanBracuk The following is where the code starts: ' <cfif ctr eq 2>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-0 col-md-2 <!---eventBox--->" id="more-events"> and the following:   <div class="eventSize eventDiv" style="border: 1px solid black;">

                                    <small>#LSDateFormat(local.item.getValue('displayStart'))#</small><br />
                                    <small><strong>#HTMLEditFormat(local.item.getValue('title'))#</strong></small><br />
                            </div>

Comment: Descriptions like "*...not able to make it work.*" are very ambiguous. Please post what have you actually tried so far and tell us what is wrong with the result.

Comment: @Leigh I have posted what what you have asked

Comment: @Leigh I have tried using divs and MOD but it does not work correctly

Comment: @RobertoFlores - Honestly that is a LOT of code, and very environment specific. It also seems more complex than necessary. For example, why not just loop through the query object instead of using an iterator. You would *greatly* increase your chances of getting an answer if you boil it down a much simpler example, that anyone could be run outside of your environment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Start by creating a manual query, loop through it and use `currentRow` and `MOD` to do something every two events.

Comment: Here is an example of an MCVE that might help you get started: http://trycf.com/gist/6ff04076185af165b7edf8348b7f1d19/acf2016?theme=monokai